# scalapb how to generate code from protobuf files in test directory?

Tags: sbt, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I'd like to generate code from protobuf files in test directory.

```
project/test/protobuf/myproto.proto
```

This doesn't work.

```
PB.targets in Test := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Test).value
)
```

Looks like scalapb only generates files for protos in main/protobuf directory.

Comment: Do you call `test:compile`? Try also `test:protoc-generate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable ScalaPB code generator for your test configuration. Add this to `build.sbt`:

```
Test / PB.targets += scalapb.gen() -> (Test / sourceManaged).value / "scalapb"
```

See https://github.com/thesamet/sbt-protoc#protos-in-other-configs

Comment: Hey @thesamet, this seems to no longer work as of July 2023. Is there a different way to do this now?

Comment: Updated the answer for recent versions of sbt-protoc.