# Maven and java: missing generated code for service in test directory

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

Following up on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55522995/3769451), I noticed still some files are not created. The files not created are for the services. The messages are created perfectly.

A quick example to reproduce my problem: 
clone for example [this github repo](https://github.com/jpdna/gRPC-maven-helloworld).

```
rm -rf src/main/java (remove java files to avoid other compilation issues)
mv src/main/proto src/test/proto (move the proto file to test)
add the following goal to pom for plugin maven-protoc-plugin: <goal>test-compile</goal>
mvn clean package
```

So the pom file should like this:
[image]

It will create these java files correctly:
[image]
but missing the GreeterGrpc (which is the service, and was created when it was in src/main/proto): 
[image]

So I am wondering how I can make the java file for service to be created when proto file is moved to test folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I realized I had only added test-compile, but not test-compile-custom. That was also needed for compiling the service java files.